# "Help pages" for my django app

Tags: django, content-management-system, wiki, django-flatpages

I am developing a django app that requires many help pages (i.e., several pages, many topics).

I am not quite sure what is the best way to do this.

I did some research and found some possible ways but they are not quite what I am looking for:

- `flatpages` => it is better if my help page authors can access a WYSIWYG interface rather than write html files
- `django-wiki` => not quite suitable because users don't need to contribute to help pages
- `django-CMS` => seems a bit of an overkill
- build my own => any examples?

What is the conventional way to add help pages to a django app?

Thanks.

Soo Ling

Comment: Depends on your requirements. "Several pages, many topics" is way to vague to be able to provide you with a suiting third part app. But sounds to me you're better off just implementing one yourself.

Comment: Something like the [airbnb help pages](https://www.airbnb.co.uk/help?ref=help-dropdown). My help pages do not need to be as fancy, but they will have a similar number of topics. The users also need to be able to search for specific topics in the help pages and this search is different from the search in my app [the search in my app returns listings].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to consider a couple of things:

1. How to access help

   Maybe have a url like `url(r'^help/(?P<topic>[-\w]+)/$', HelpView.as_view()),` and have the topic be a slug.
2. How to organize help

   Have a `TopicHelp` model that is related to the topic (whatever model that may be). I suspect it may be a `OneToMany` (or M2M) relationship, as a help page may be connected to many topics. You could use TinyMCE to give editors wysiwyg capabilities on HelpTopics.

If you're using the Admin, this would be very easy to implement and control.

That's how I'd look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I might just try what you suggested.